# Client that can manage users in Keycloak 23+

Tags: keycloak

I need to authorize my application (named "Logic" from now on) to manage users of a Keycloak realm. "Logic" already authenticates itself against that realm with a client credentials grant access type, so the code is already working.

Now, in the Keycloak administration console, I need to add the correct role to my client  so that "Logic" is authorized to call whatever API endpoint Keycloak provides to manage the realm users.

In the realm clients list there is a client named `realm-management`, which Keycloak provides by default for each realm. This client can manage the whole realm, not just its users, and it has a list of client roles for that reason. `manage-users` is one of the roles in that list and it is the role I need to assign to my other client (that I named `logic` in Keycloak). In other words, my "Logic" application uses the keycloak client-id `logic` to authenticate itself and I need to add the `manage-users` role to the `logic` client.

The problem is that in my client (`logic`) roles settings, those same roles, listed under `realm-management` client, are not listed at all, and the list only has `uma_protection` role:

[image: The list only has uma_protection]

If I searched for "manage-users" by typing it in the search box, it wouldn't show up. Meanwhile, if I click that role in the roles list of the `realm-management` client, it shows that no *users* have that role and it lets me add the role to *users*, but not to *clients*, even if that role is actually listed in a *client* (`realm-management`).

Creating a new role in my `logic` client, by the same name of `manage-users`, is possible, but I'm not sure that's the way to go. I mean, why should I duplicate an existing role? It smells of wrong.

Can you please tell me the correct way to add the `manage-users` role to a *client* in Keycloak 23?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally [got an answer](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/client-that-can-manage-users-in-keycloak-23/24302/2?u=lucrus) from a member of the official Keycloak support community, and I report that here just in case others were to find my question here.

dasniko wrote:

> If your client already uses the client credentials flow, it has
> “service accounts” enabled. You have to *assign* the
> `realm-management.manage-users` role to the service account in the
> resp. tab of your client. This way the corresponding service account
> user, which is responsible in Keycloak for getting the client
> credentials flow to work, will get the proper role and should be able
> to manage your users.

The roles can be found by selecting the filter for "Filter by clients" instead of "Filter by realm roles"